# Ag-Grid Store paginated data

Tags: reactjs, redux, ag-grid

How to store paginated data of Ag-Grid

Have a feature GotoPage10, GotoPage50, ...

When navigated to Page10, Page50 (only corresponding data will be fetched from backend)

Want to save this data (only have data for random pages 1, 15, 20, ..)

and if component loaded again after an unmount. Dont want to make backend calls for already fetched data

How to do it ?

Answer (score 0):

A way to solve this is not by using Redux or AG Grid. Instead, you will need to cache your HTTP responses in a caching mechanism for your application. This will require a singleton service that maintains a [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) object where your request call is the key, and the response is the value. Whenever your app invokes a fetch from the browser, have the query and response saved in the Map. Of course, you will want to check if the request is already in the Map object before making the call to the backend. If a response is already present, then you can skip the HTTP call to the server.